# How do I count the time between purchases for different users, using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a set of purchase data that looks like the following:

User        Date
user_a  date_1
user_b  date_2
user_a  date_3
user_a  date_4
user_c  date_5
user_b  date_6
user_c  date_7
etc.

I would like to find the average time between purchases for each user.

Any help?

I'm using jupyter notebook.

Comment: (max(date) - min(date)) / #purchases,   for each user

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: any code you tried?

Comment: I tried a pivot table:

pd.pivot_table(df, index=['user'], values='successful_transaction', columns=['date']).reset_index()

but that only gives me a visual way of seeing when a purchase was made for each user.

note: successful_transaction is a column that has binary values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is a dataframe with 'User' as a column and 'date' another column.

```
df.groupby('User').mean()
```

if this didn't work because of date format (string), you might have to change date format using

> pd.to_datetime

or convert date to days

Comment: Tried this. the date format is now: "non-null datetime64[ns]".  

But i still get:  DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: What is your date format? Is it dd:mm:yyyy:hh:mm:ss or just mm:dd:yyy ? It's better to convert to days with a reference year